# Paperclip using S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use Paperclip gem and store the documents on Amazon S3.

In my gemfile, I have:

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-s3'
```

In my model, I have (with the correct bucket and keys):

```
  has_attached_file :attach,
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => ENV['mybucket'],
  :s3_credentials => {
    :access_key_id => ENV['mykey'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['mysecretkey']
  }
```

But, I get the following error:

```
Missing credentials
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your `ENV['mykey']` and `ENV['mysecretkey']` environment variables are actually defined.

Comment: I thought I was supposed to put the actual values in my code.  But, when you mentioned variables, I realized that I needed to set the variables on Heroku.  Now it works fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this. In your model

```
 has_attached_file :attach,
 :styles => {
 :thumb=> "100x100#"},
 :storage => :s3,
 :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
 :path => ":attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
 :bucket => 'bucket_name'
```

Then create a s3.yml file in your config folder in place the following code there

```
development:
  bucket: bucketname
  access_key_id: xxx
  secret_access_key: xxx
test:
  bucket: bucketname
  access_key_id: xxx
  secret_access_key: xxx
production:
  bucket: bucketname
  access_key_id: xxx
secret_access_key: xxx
```

This is a more cleaner way to go about doing something like so.